# how to properly send the response code from Node.js API

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I have a simple node-based API, which needs to parse some JSON, save some data into Postgres, and then, send the appropriate response code (like http 201).
My code looks like this:

```
router.route('/customer')

    .post(function(req, res) {
        Customers = req.body;
        var numberOfCustomers = Customers.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < Customers.length; i++){
            Customer = Customers[i];
            console.log(Customer.Name  + "  " + Customer.Address);
            var date = moment(new Date()).unix();

            client.query(
                'INSERT into customer (name, address, date_modified) VALUES($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id',
                [Customer.Name, Customer.Address, date],
                function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        status = 1;
                    } else {
                        console.log('row inserted with id: ' + result.rows[0].id);
                        if(numberOfCustomers === i) {
                            res.status(201).send({ message: "created" });
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    })
```

I'm getting this error:

_

```
http_outgoing.js:344
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
```

I need to account for the fact, that I'm performing my Postgres insert multiple times within a loop, so I can not send my response headers after just the first insert is done.

What is the most appropriate place within my 'POST' handler to put my `res.status(201).send({ message: "created" });`
?

Comment: The most appropriate place is where you want to send *the single response* to the request. It's completely up to your requirements where that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Architectural decisions aside (for example, you might want a separate module that acts as an HTTP adapter to handle logic for sending response codes as opposed to doing it inside of your route controller), you can use promises to wait for all the inserts to finish and then send a *single* response code. For example, something like this:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var query = Promise.promisify(client.query);

router.route('/customer')
.post(function(req, res) {
   // all your logic, and then

   return Promise.all(Customers.map(function() {
     return query(sql, [Customer.Name, Customer.Address, date]);
   })
   .then(function() {
     res.status(201).send({ message: 'Created' });
   });
});
```

Check out the [the bluebird docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) for the API used in this example.

I'm unfamiliar with Postgres's API, but the concept should be similar: you need to wait for all the requests to your DB to be resolved first.

Comment: Why not just use the native implementation of promises?

Comment: @cbass if you're using the latest node.js, then yeah you can use the native implementation of promises. Or if you're using an older version and want to transpile your es6 to es5, that's an option as well.

Answer (score 2):

As stated above: Yes, async helpers such as Promises and async are beneficial for such matters. However, I do believe the 'best' way to solve this problem is to only use a single query. Instead of only performing one insert per query, batch them all up in to a single query like so:

```
INSERT into customer (name, address, date_modified)
VALUES
   ($1, $2, $3),
   ($4, $5, $6),
   ($7, $8, $9),
   ...
RETURNING id'
```

Suggestion

```
router.route('/customer').post(function(req, res) {

    //Fetch customers
    var customers = req.body;

    //Store parameters and query inserts for db-query.
    var params = [];
    var inserts = [];

    //For each customer
    // - Add parameters for query
    // - Build insert string
    customers.forEach(function(customer){
       inserts.push(
         [
           "($",
           params.push(customer.Name),
           ", $",
           params.push(customer.Address),
           ", ",
           NOW(), //unnecessary to generate timestamp in js
           ")",
         ].join('')
       )
    });

    //Build query
    var query = 'INSERT into customer (name, address, date_modified) VALUES '+ inserts +' RETURNING id';

    //Query database in a more simple fashion.
    client.query(query, params, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            status = 1;
        } else {
            res.status(201).send({ message: "created" });
        });
    }
})
```

If you're using ES6 you are able to simplify the string build operations by using string templating.

```
customers.forEach(function(customer){
    var query = `($${params.push(customer.Name)}, $${params.push(customer.Address)}, NOW())`
    inserts.push(query);
});

//and

var query = `
    INSERT into customer (name, address, date_modified)
    VALUES ${inserts}
    RETURNING id
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way be to do, I would also recommend you look into `Async or lodash lib`.

```
router.route('/customer')

.post(function(req, res) {
    var Customers = req.body,
        numberOfCustomers = Customers.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < Customers.length; i++){
        var Customer = Customers[i];
        console.log(Customer.Name  + "  " + Customer.Address);
        var date = moment(new Date()).unix(),
            sql = 'INSERT into customer (name, address, date_modified) VALUES($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id';

        client.query(sql, [Customer.Name, Customer.Address, date],
            function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(500).json({message: "Server Error", err: err});
                } else {
                    console.log('row inserted with id: ' + result.rows[0].id);
                    if (numberOfCustomers === i) {
                        res.status(201).send({ message: "Created" });
                    }
                }
            });
    }
})
```

Comment: This unfortunately will result in the same issue that the OP is seeing. You're mutating headers within a loop. So after the first iteration, you'll get an error

Comment: True @Seth but that `if` block will only return when there's an error, plus send back the `error stack`, for the particular `object` in the `Array` that couldn't be processed. I think there should be an exit as well just to keep the db clean

Comment: What if the first iteration succeeds and the second one fails? The headers will already be set and response terminated at that point, resulting in the existing issue again.